# How I email implement in query on my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a MongoDB API I create  '/inventoryItems' this API already shows for all Inventory items

This is my back-end database FORM data

```
{ _id:2749d97592b4b1d084e20a2
    supplierName:"carsale"
    email:"imd572258@gmail.com"
    brand:"audi"
    quantity:"1"
    price:"520"
    description:"car want need want "
    img:"https://res.cloudinary.com/dk0lorahh/image/upload/v1648239069/
  }
```

How i do use const email = req.query.eamil
const query={email :email}

app.get("/inventoryItems", async (req, res) => {

```
  const page= parseInt(req.query.page);
  const size =  parseInt(req.query.size);
  **const email = req.query.email**
  const query = {}; 
  const cursor = inventoryItemsCollection.find(query);    
  let inventoryItems ;
  if( page || size ){

    inventoryItems = await cursor.skip(page*size).limit(size).toArray();
    
    
  }else{

    inventoryItems = await cursor.toArray();
  }
  res.send(inventoryItems);
});

  **if i do like this** 

const page= parseInt(req.query.page);
  const size =  parseInt(req.query.size);
  const email = req.query.email
  **const query = {email: email};** 
  const cursor = inventoryItemsCollection.find(query);    
  let inventoryItems ;
  if( page || size ){

    inventoryItems = await cursor.skip(page*size).limit(size).toArray();


  }else{

    inventoryItems = await cursor.toArray();
  }
  res.send(inventoryItems);
});
```

it's working find the email result but When mY **Form data are not working not showing**

```
 showing empty 
     []
```

I want a way how to do both works email results and my form results showing

Comment: Are page and size being set correctly

Comment: yes  set correctly